# Check historical balance of ERC20 tokens of wallets

Tags: blockchain, tokens

I'm currently working for an audit company and one of the things that I'd like to know to expedite/speed up the process regarding cryptocurrencies is that would there be a way to check historical balance of ERC20 tokens in a wallet at a certain date (say 31 December 2021) quickly and efficiently? And would it be possible to do this for several wallet addresses at the same time?

Any thoughts or suggestions on how I could automate this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might need to use a data indexing solution such as [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) to fork the mainnet at a certain block heigh.

The code would look like this:

```
vm.createSelectFork(vm.envString("ETH_RPC_URL"), BLOCKHEIGHTDESIRED);
```

and then you can simply query the balance of eth or any erc20 you want from any addresses you want from that block height